# Is there a way to get a list of all the users on a domain using ASP.NET with C# as the backend?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The question basically says it all.  I want to be able to get a list of all the users on the windows domain (i.e. in the active directory) using c#.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be easier to do things on the SQL side (generate a view of all users). Can I assume you are willing to use SQL Server?

Comment: I am using SQL Server as well, but my authentication must be with the windows domain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", "x.y.com", "DC=x,DC=y,DC=com"));
var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
         {
             Filter = "(&(&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person)))"
         };
var resultCollection = searcher.FindAll();
```

SEE:  [Get all users from AD domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674158/get-all-users-from-ad-domain?tab=votes)

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  How do I know what needs to be passed into the constructor of the DirectoryEntry object?  I'm confused about the parameters of that string.

Comment: Those are your AD Company identifiers. Company Name, Company Country...etc.