# Get all users in Active Directory group

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I'm trying to get all users that belong to a group in the Active Directory. I want to display the result as a drop down for the site users to select. This is what I have so far:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetAllMembers(string group)
{
    var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, group);

    return from principal in @group.Members select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(/* need to fill in key and value */);
}
```

The problem I have is that I am developing this outside of an active directory so cannot really test it yet (long story don't ask). I want to maximise my chances of success when deploying this into a testing environment.

My question is: if I want the key value pair to contain login username (key, ex: `"DOMAIN\darkoz"`) and the users real name (value, ex: `"Darko Z"`), how do I get those? the `Principal` object has at least 5 properties with the word `Name` in it so I'm not sure which is which.

Bonus question: is this a generally accepted way of achieving my goal? I realize it is a very simple problem but with my lack of knowledge of Active Directory, I wouldn't be surprised if there was a better way of doing this. Will this work running on an account that is not admin?

Comment: Even if it is not your real problem, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810613/how-to-find-all-groups-in-activedirectory-where-the-current-user-has-writepropert) can give you some additional ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was as I suspected:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetAllMembers(string group)
{
    var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    var groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, group);

    return from m
           in groupPrincipal.Members 
           select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(m.SamAccountName, m.Name);
}
```

where the `SamAccountName` gives the users logon name and the `Name` is the actual name

Answer (score 0):

I would read previous similar questions to answer both of your questions, about best practices and about how to read accountname and full name: [Get all users from AD domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674158/get-all-users-from-ad-domain)

anyway, from MS forum:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string groupName = "Domain Users";
    string domainName = "";

    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
    GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);

    if (grp != null)
    {
         foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(false))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.SamAccountName + " - " + p.DisplayName);
            }


        grp.Dispose();
        ctx.Dispose();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nWe did not find that group in that domain, perhaps the group resides in a different domain?");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

source: [Get list of Active Directory users in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/ecb16a63-6619-4c68-a77c-8bb2682fc1be)